# Eigenvalues of a block diagonal symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

If we hava a block diagonal matrix $M$,
\begin{equation}
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1} & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & d_{1}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $d_{1}$ is ($4 \times 4$) symmetric matrix,
\begin{equation}
d_{1}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     a & b & c & b \\
     b & a & b & c \\
     c & b & a & b \\
     b & c & b & a
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

then how we will find the eigenvalues of $M$ ?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $d_1$ will be the same as the eigenvalues of $M$, but with multiplicities multiplied by the number of copies of $d_1$ in $M$.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of $M$ will be the eigenvalues of $d_1$. It turns out that the eigenvalues of $d_1$ are $a-c$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $a+c\pm2b$.

Comment: Right. My mistake. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: so sir, in this case what will be the exact eigenvalues of $M$

Comment: sir if possible and  can provide me any reference ....

Comment: They will be $a-c$, $a+c+2b$ and $a+c-2b$, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: i mean any book or article which explain this term(block matrix eigenvalues )

Comment: I suppose that any Linear Algebra texbook will tell you that the determinant of a block matrix$$M=\begin{bmatrix}B_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&B_2&0&\ldots&0\\&\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&B_n\end{bmatrix}$$is equal to $\det(B_1)\det(B_2)\cdots\det(B_n)$. Therefore, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is the product of the characteristic polynomials of the $B_k$'s and then the set of the eigenvalues of $M$ is the union of the sets of the eigenvalues of the $B_k$'s.